# EF Core Many to many relashionship for the same entity and make a separate table for it

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've searched a lot of answers at StackOverflow but still I haven't found an answer.

I have such class

```
public class Film
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid FilmId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int FilmApiId { get; set; }
    public List<Genre> FilmGenres { get; set; } = new();
    public IList<Film> SimilarFilms { get; set; } = new List<Film>();
    public List<Image> FilmImages { get; set; } = new();
}
```

After migration I've got such situation in database
[Screen of tables from db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/345u8.png)
And I've got only 2 of 3 tables in it. I want to have 3 tables making on a fly. The "missing" one is SimilarFilms.
OnModelCreating is empty.

And what I've got instead of third table is one more field in Films table "FilmId1".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a many-to-many relationship. At least, I'm guessing you're taking about the "similar films"? A film can be similar to many other films that can have many other similar films.

Comment: You are right. I just thought about a variant at least for one film and forgout about other variants

Comment: Read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) regarding many to many relationships. Actually that link is quite extensive regarding other relationships.

Comment: I need to ask if I need for this sutuation one more class to make it work?

Comment: I'm not sure actually. Maybe this will already work `modelBuilder.Entity<Film>().HasMany(f => f.SimilarFilms).WithMany(f => f.SimilarFilms)`

Comment: Nah, I tried it, it doesn't work. Good question. I will ask the EF developers.